# Name for factoring out repeated code into separate function

Tags: design-patterns, language-agnostic, refactoring

I'm trying to find research/advice on a particular code refactoring pattern, but I'm finding it hard to locate, since I'm not sure whether there's a good name for it.  It's very similar to factoring out repeated code, except the code wasn't repeated in the first place: it was just stashed away in a conditional branch of a larger function, accessible via a parameter of that function.

In pseudocode, the before:

```
function frobnicate(id, check_only = false) {
    if id cannot be frobnicated
        return false
    if check_only
        return true
    // frobnicate id
    return true
}

// example calls:
okay_to_frobnicate = frobnicate(id, true)
frobnicate_success = frobnicate(id)
```

After:

```
function can_be_frobnicated(id) {
    if id cannot be frobnicated
        return false
    else
        return true
}

function frobnicate(id) {
    if not can_be_frobnicated(id)
        return false
    // frobnicate id
    return true
}

// example calls:
okay_to_frobnicate = can_be_frobnicated(id)
frobnicate_success = frobnicate(id)
```

**Edit**: added example calls.  Wasn't clear that the removed parameter was part of the refactoring.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The pattern used to factor out repeated code into separate methods is called "[extract method refactoring](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html)".

Comment: Wow! That was quick, and is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks.

Comment: Welcome! Although your final code is a little bit different than the result of that refactoring. What happened to that `check_only` parameter?

Comment: This is what threw me at first.  The check only is external now, since the check function is separated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a basic case of OO [modularity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_%28programming%29).  You're separating out two discrete processes that don't *necessarily* have to go together.